# How to make script work for all players Unity Photon?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

> I want all players to be able to move and throw gameObjects in the scene
>   with this script:

```
 [RequireComponent( typeof( PhotonView ) )]
 public class PickupObjectNetwork : Photon.MonoBehaviour {
 public GameObject mainCamera;    
 public bool carrying;
 GameObject carriedObject;
 public float distance;
 public float smooth;
 public float throwPower = 10f;
 private float chargeTime = 0f;    
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
     mainCamera = GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera");            
 }
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
     if(photonView.isMine)
     {            
         if(carriedObject == null)
         {
             carrying = false;
         }
         if(gameObject == null)
             return;

         if(carrying) {
             photonView.RPC("carry", PhotonTargets.AllBuffered);
             photonView.RPC("checkDrop", PhotonTargets.AllBuffered);

             if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {
                 float pushForce = chargeTime * 10;
                 pushForce = Mathf.Clamp (pushForce, 1, 20);
                 photonView.RPC("throwObject", PhotonTargets.AllBuffered, pushForce);
                 chargeTime = 0;
             }                
         } else {
             if(Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.E)) {                    
                 photonView.RPC("pickup", PhotonTargets.AllBuffered);
             }
         }
         if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
             chargeTime += Time.deltaTime;
         }
     }
 }
 [PunRPC]
 void carry() {            
     if (carriedObject == null)
     {
         return;
     }        
     Debug.Log("picked up object with id: " + carriedObject.GetComponent<PhotonView>().viewID);
     carriedObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (carriedObject.transform.position, mainCamera.transform.position + mainCamera.transform.forward * distance, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
     carriedObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
 }
 [PunRPC]
 void pickup() {                
         int x = Screen.width / 2;
         int y = Screen.height / 2;
         Ray ray = mainCamera.GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(x,y));
         RaycastHit hit;
         if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
             Pickupable p = hit.collider.GetComponent<Pickupable>();
             if(p != null && hit.distance < 5) {
                 carrying = true;
                 carriedObject = p.gameObject;                                
                 p.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.zero;
                 p.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;                            
             }
         }        
 }
 [PunRPC]
 void checkDrop() {            
     if(Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.E)) {
         dropObject();
     }
 }
 [PunRPC]
 void dropObject() {        
     carrying = false;        
     carriedObject.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = true;
     carriedObject = null;
 }
 [PunRPC]
 void throwObject(float pushForce){            
     carrying = false;
     if(carriedObject.tag != "BoxMultiplayer")
         carriedObject.tag = "Projectile";
     carriedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce(Camera.main.transform.forward * pushForce * 200);
     carriedObject.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().useGravity = true;            
     carriedObject = null;
 }    
 }
```

> I instantiate scene objects using
>   PhotonNetwork.InstantiateSceneObject(); This script works only for
>   master client, non-master clients can not move objects.
>
> I also tried this script (randomly): http://pastebin.com/7DgjZ9U7
>   I don`t really know how to work with AllocateViewId(). When i use this
>   script, both players can move sceneObjects, but object movement is not
>   synchronized (object positions are not updating for other players).
>   Also, when one of the players throws gameObject into
>   the wall, which destroys new collisions with PhotonNetwork.Destroy(),
>   this player freezes in place for others. 
>   Hope that my question is not super messy. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If a player without authority over the object handles it, the changes will not be synced to the other players. In order to do that every player need to request ownership for that object using the method `photonView.RequestOwnership()` before pickup/throw/carry it.

There is also a complete example on how to request ownership on the Photon Unity package (*DemoChangeOwner-Scene.unity*).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have tried experimenting with photonView.RequestOwnership() before, but did not succeed, i have also checked DemoChangeOwner-Scene, and put photonView.RequestOwnership() in pickup() function, but it didn`t work. Can you tell me please, in which function should i write it?

Comment: You should call every time a player needs to change the transform of an object that he is not the owner. Just remember that in order to change the owner of an object the OwnershipOption must be set to Request or Takeover.

Comment: My gameObject`s photonView is set to request, i also put photonView.RequestOwnership() in carry() function => in Update() function which is bad, but i wanted to test it. And still it does not work. Both players freeze in place for each other after trying to grab the object. ................Debug.Log: Ev OwnershipRequest: {245=System.Int32[], 254=1} ViewID: 1001 from: 1 Time: 709   ..................                                                    Ev OwnershipRequest PhotonView.ownershipTransfer: Takeover .ownerId: 1 isOwnerActive: True. This client's player: #01 '' {}